# spring cloud dataflow input source kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have problem with a common task and i can find any solutions or help (maybe some properties i need to pass for this to work ?)
I use local server 1.3.0.M2 and create simple stream

```
dataflow:>stream create --name test --definition ":bosstds > log" --deploy
```

In log i got this :

> 2017-09-28 12:31:00.644 INFO 5156 --- [ -C-1]
>   o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator : Successfully joined group
>   test with generation 1
>       2017-09-28 12:31:00.646 INFO 5156 --- [ -C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator : Setting newly assigned
>   partitions [bosstds-0] for group test
>       2017-09-28 12:31:00.671 INFO 5156 --- [ -C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$3 : partitions
>   assigned:[bosstds-0]
>       2017-09-28 12:37:08.898 ERROR 5156 --- [ -L-1] **o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder : Could not convert message:**
>   **74657374**
>       java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 103
>       at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:385) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.lang.String.(String.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.EmbeddedHeaderUtils.oldExtractHeaders(EmbeddedHeaderUtils.java:154)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.M2.jar!/:1.3.0.M2]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.EmbeddedHeaderUtils.extractHeaders(EmbeddedHeaderUtils.java:115)
>   ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.0.M2.jar!/:1.3.0.M2]

message is produced with kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic bosstds and simply send line "test"

any suggestions ?

Comment: SCDF is a simple orchestration tool. All the action lies in the Spring Cloud Stream applications. It'd help if you can edit the post with the version of `log-sink` and Kafka that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

SCS embed headers on kafka in order to get this working set header mode to raw. You need to do that when interfacing with external apps not using SCS

Comment: @Berislav: Vinicius is referring to `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.headerMode=raw` property. Where `<channelName>` in your case for the OOTB log-sink application, it would be `output`. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_consumer_properties) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

tnx for help. I fixed this with:

```
 --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=text/plain
 --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw
```